# How to add header to HttpRequest of GET method in Java

Tags: java, web-services, rest, http-headers, access-token

I have to pass a token as part of validation for each GET request to access RESTful web service. Below is the code I'm using it to access REST api:

```
public static String httpGet(String urlStr, String[] paramName, String[] paramVal) throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL(urlStr);
        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 

        OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
        Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8");
        for (int i = 0; i < paramName.length; i++) {
            writer.write(paramName[i]);
            writer.write("=");
            writer.write(URLEncoder.encode(paramVal[i], "UTF-8"));
            writer.write("&");
        }
        writer.close();
        out.close();

        if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            System.out.println("Response code: "+conn.getResponseCode());
            throw new IOException(conn.getResponseMessage());
        }

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        rd.close();

        conn.disconnect();
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

I can't see any such method to set Header `conn.setHeader()` provided for HttpsURLConnection. It should be something like  ***X-Cookie: token={token};*** please help me to find a way to set header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
conn.addRequestProperty("X-Cookie", "token={token}");
```

or `setRequestProperty()` also works

Answer (score 1):

You are already setting headers on your request in your code when you do the following:

> ```
>     conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
> ```

I.e. if the service you are communicating with requires that you send your token in the "X-Cookie" header you can simply do the same for that header:

```
conn.setRequestProperty("X-Cookie", "token={token}");
```